# OS app based on cryptocurrency in review process

Tags: ios

I am an iOS developer. My app is cryptocurrency app. I uploaded app build on itunesconnect. but it is in review from last 2 months meanwhile i had contact app review team but they always give same response your app is in review. I rejected app by developer rejected option and again upload new build. But it give same response again for long time in review. What can be reason of this stuck.
I am stuck how can i live my app.

Answer (score -1):

**Expedited App Review**
If you face extenuating circumstances, you can request the review of your app to be expedited. These circumstances include fixing a critical bug in your app on the App Store or releasing your app to coincide with an event you are directly associated with.

Urgent Bug Fix
If you've submitted an update to fix a critical bug in your app on the App Store and you are requesting an expedited review, be sure to include the steps to reproduce the bug on the current version of your app.

Time-Sensitive Event
For apps associated with an event, we recommend you plan and schedule the release of your app in iTunes Connect. However, if your app is still in review and the launch of your event is quickly approaching, you can request to have your app review expedited. When submitting your request, it's important to include the event, date of the event, and your app's association with the event.

Please Note: Expedited reviews are granted on a limited basis and we cannot guarantee that every request will be expedited.

[Expediting an App Review - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-review/)

[image: critical bug fix]

[image: time sensitive event]

The two screenshots above are from “request an expedited app review” form. "Select a reason” has two options: “Critical Bug Fix” or “Time-Sensitive Event” and provide proper reasoning for the same to complete the process and approved the review process will take maximum 24h to get completed.

Comment: I already try this all options. In expedited review they give same response that your app is already in review and i requested about  time sensitive event also but couldn't got help

Comment: @ParveenKhan.. try to give some unavoidable reasoning to expedite the review, else they will not process your request.

Comment: So your advice is basically "lie to the review team" since both cases of the review process are not suited for OP, this will certainly not get you very far...

Comment: @luk2302, please read my post's last paragraph. I talked about proper reasoning, not a lie.

Comment: Neither is OP producing a critical bug fix nor has he a time-sensitive 
event coming up: Expedited App Review is **not** suited.

Comment: I hope it's not you who posted the question here, let him decide not you.

Comment: @luk2302, it's a forum to help other developers not to criticize. I hope you understand that better than me.

Comment: actually my reason is genuine and they understand also my reason but still they said we can't tell you how much time it will take.